# Running BenchmarkDotNet within XUnit

Tags: c#, .net-core, xunit, benchmarkdotnet

I am using .NET Core 3.1 in my project (web api, VS2019) and XUnit 2.4.1. Recently I was thinking about adding some performance tests and I came accross this  library - [BenchmarkDotNet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/). Since I've already been using XUnit for other tests I wanted to run **BenchmarkDotNet** from within the XUnit *[Fact]s*.

I found this [post](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet/issues/558) where it is explained that shadow copies of assemblies must be turned off for xunit. So I tried following:

1. To keep it simple I have created fresh new **.net core 3.1** console application project with sample method I wanted to benchmark:

```
[SimpleJob(RuntimeMoniker.NetCoreApp31)]
[MinColumn, MaxColumn, MedianColumn, KurtosisColumn]
[HtmlExporter]
public class TestScenarios
{
    [Params("test")]
    public string TextToHash { get; set; }

    [Benchmark]
    public string CalculateSha256()
    {
        var engine = SHA256.Create();
        var hash = engine.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(TextToHash));
        return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(hash);
    }
}
```

Then in **Program.cs** I have:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BenchmarkRunner.Run<TestScenarios>();
    }
}
```

When compiling and runnning the application in **Release** I verified that *BenchmarkDotNet.Artifacts* folder with log and benchmark output files were correctly created.

2. I've added XUnit project to the solution and created simple **[Fact]** method:

```
public class DotNetBenchmarkTest
{
    [Fact]
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        BenchmarkRunner.Run<TestScenarios>();
    }
}
```

Also building in **Release** configuration and running this method from test explorer will create *BenchmarkDotNet.Artifacts* folder in *bin/Release/dotnetcoreapp3.1/* but log files are empty.

3. I've also tried to add **xunit.runner.json** file with following contents to the root of my XUnit project:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://xunit.net/schema/current/xunit.runner.schema.json",
  "shadowCopy": false,
  "methodDisplay": "classAndMethod",
  "diagnosticMessages": true
}
```

but seems to have no effect on the behavior - I verified that file *xunit.runner.json* is copied to the output bin directory (Properties->Copy to Output Directory->Copy always).

4. I also installed *xUnit.net Console Runner v2.4.1* and tried to run the tests from the console:

```
xunit .\path\assembly-name.dll -noshadow
```

Again no luck. The option **-noshadow** I found at this [github link](https://gist.github.com/StephenCavender/2c635ff4e674a283c14c25f8a841152e). Seems like the option was available in the older version but is not listed my help output for *xunit console runner v2.4.1* but I gave it a try.

So my question is if it is possible to get DotNetBenchmarkTest working altogether with XUnit and if so, can you point me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you get a resolution to this?  Running via tests, my Benchmark methods just say "N/A"

Comment: Also make sure you are running in Release mode. At least that is what I had to do. `dotnet test -c Release`.

Comment: Try to check the log file in your BenchmarkDotNet.Artifacts folder and deal with any issue there. Mine is "Assembly xx which defines benchmarks references xx; If you own this dependency, please, build it in RELEASE. If you don't, you can disable this policy by using 'config.WithOptions(ConfigOptions.DisableOptimizationsValidator)'. I ended up using the config according to their documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a wrapper test fixture that runs the benchmarks, collects the output and prints the summary at the end:

```
public class Benchmarks
{
    private readonly ITestOutputHelper output;

    public Benchmarks(ITestOutputHelper output)
    {
        this.output = output;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Run_Benchmarks()
    {
        var logger = new AccumulationLogger();

        var config = ManualConfig.Create(DefaultConfig.Instance)
            .AddLogger(logger)
            .WithOptions(ConfigOptions.DisableOptimizationsValidator);

        BenchmarkRunner.Run<FooBenchmarks>(config);

        // write benchmark summary
        output.WriteLine(logger.GetLog());
    }
}

[MemoryDiagnoser]
public class FooBenchmarks
{
    [GlobalSetup]
    public void Setup()
    {
        ModuleInitializer.Initialize();
        ...
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public async Task ProcessRequest_Benchmark()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am running BenchmarkDotNet benchmarks within XUnit tests.

Make sure that your project is referencing these NuGet packages

- xunit
- xunit.runner.visualstudio
- Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk

Then you can run the xunit tests from Visual Studio or with `dotnet test` via command-line  since this is .NET Core project.

`xunit.console.runner` is capable of running .NET Framework projects.

Check [here](https://xunit.net/docs/nuget-packages) and [here](https://xunit.net/docs/getting-started/netcore/cmdline) for more explanation.